# Confused about java concurrency results

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So I am studying up on java concurrency by trying to create bad concurrent examples, watch them fail and then fix them.

But the code never seems to be breaking... What am I missing here?

I have a "shared object", being my HotelWithMaximum instance. As far as I can tell, this class is not thread safe:

```
package playground.concurrent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HotelWithMaximum {

    private static final int MAXIMUM = 20;

    private List<String> visitors = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void register(IsVisitor visitor) {
        System.out.println("Registering : " + visitor.getId());
        System.out.println("Amount of visitors atm: " + visitors.size());

        if(visitors.size() < MAXIMUM) {
            //At some point, I do expect a thread to be interfering here where the condition is actually evaluated to
            //true, but some other thread interfered, adds another visitor, causing the previous thread to go over the limit
            System.out.println("REGISTERING ---------------------------------------------------------------------");
            //The interference might also happen here i guess...
            visitors.add(visitor.getId());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("We cant register anymore, we have reached our limit! " + visitors.size());
        }
    }

    public int getAmountOfRegisteredVisitors() {
        return visitors.size();
    }

    public void printVisitors() {
        for(String visitor: visitors) {
            System.out.println(visitors.indexOf(visitor) + " - " + visitor);
        }
    }
}
```

The visitors are 'Runnables' (they implement my interface IsVisitor which extends from Runnable), and they are implemented like this:

```
package playground.concurrent.runnables;

import playground.concurrent.HotelWithMaximum;
import playground.concurrent.IsVisitor;

public class MaxHotelVisitor implements IsVisitor{

    private final String id;
    private final HotelWithMaximum hotel;

    public MaxHotelVisitor(String id, HotelWithMaximum hotel) {
        this.hotel = hotel;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(String.format("My name is %s and I am trying to register...", id));
        hotel.register(this);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

Then, to make all of this run in an example, I have the following code in a different class:

```
public static void executeMaxHotelExample() {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
        HotelWithMaximum hotel = new HotelWithMaximum();

        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            executor.execute(new MaxHotelVisitor("MaxHotelVisitor-" + i, hotel));
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        try{
            boolean finished = executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if(finished) {
                System.out.println("FINISHED WITH THE MAX HOTEL VISITORS EXAMPLE");
                hotel.printVisitors();
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Something interrupted me....");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executeMaxHotelExample();
    }
```

Now, what am I missing? Why does this never seem to fail? The hotel class is not thread safe, right? And the only thing to make it 'enough' thread safe for this example (since no other code is messing with the thread unsafe List in the hotel class ), I should just make the register method "synchronized", right?
The result of the "printVisitors()" method in the main method, always looks like this:

```
FINISHED WITH THE MAX HOTEL VISITORS EXAMPLE
0 - MaxHotelVisitor-0
1 - MaxHotelVisitor-6
2 - MaxHotelVisitor-7
3 - MaxHotelVisitor-8
4 - MaxHotelVisitor-9
5 - MaxHotelVisitor-10
6 - MaxHotelVisitor-11
7 - MaxHotelVisitor-12
8 - MaxHotelVisitor-13
9 - MaxHotelVisitor-14
10 - MaxHotelVisitor-15
11 - MaxHotelVisitor-16
12 - MaxHotelVisitor-17
13 - MaxHotelVisitor-18
14 - MaxHotelVisitor-19
15 - MaxHotelVisitor-20
16 - MaxHotelVisitor-21
17 - MaxHotelVisitor-22
18 - MaxHotelVisitor-23
19 - MaxHotelVisitor-24
```

There are nevere more then 20 visitors in the list... I find that quite weird...

Comment: Firstly a small sample size might be unlikely to demonstrate concurrency issues. Maybe run this same expirment a million times? Secondly you might want to add after the line where you print to sysout `REGISTERING` a `Thread.sleep(x)` or `Thread.yield()` to try to encourage the issue to appear at that point.

Comment: hmmm, that might indeed be a possibility, i ll look into that. I had some disturbing results with another test pretty fast though...

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is from the `java.util.concurrent` package

> The Java Concurrency Utilities framework in the java.util.concurrent package is a library that contains thread-safe types that are used to handle concurrency in Java applications

So `ThreadPoolExecutor` is taking care of the syncorinous processing

take note: `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses `BlockingQueue` to manage its job queue 
`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` is an interface that request all implementations to be thread-safe.

From my understanding one of the main goals of `java.util.concurrent` was that you can to a large extent operate without the need to use java's low-level concurrency primitives `synchronized, volatile, wait(), notify(), and notifyAll()` which are difficult to use.

Also note that `ThreadPoolExecutor` implements `ExecutorService` which does not guarantee all implementations are thread-safe but according to the documentation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

> Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService **happen-before** any actions taken by that task, which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via Future.get().

Explanation of **`happen-before`**:

> *Java™ Language Specification* defines the happens-before relation on memory operations such as reads and writes of shared variables. The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread **only** if the write operation happens-before the read operation.

In other words - generally not thread-safe. BUT

> The methods of all classes in **java.util.concurrent** and its subpackages extend these guarantees to **higher-level synchronization**.

Comment: Hmm, I am really struggling with that quote from the documentation. What I get from it is that the executorService somehow guarantees the happen-before contract... but how?

Comment: @ocket-san check out the updated answer - I hope this does a better job at clarifying

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll investigate deeper, because I still think I understand it wrong. But I ll get back to your answer for sure!

Answer (score 1):

> the code never seems to be breaking... What am I missing here?

The Java Language Specification gives implementors a lot of leeway to make the most efficient use of any given multi-processor architecture.

If you obey the rules for writing "safe" multi-threaded code, then that's supposed to guarantee that a correctly implemented JVM will run your program in the way that you expect.  But if you *break* the rules, that does *not* guarantee that your program will misbehave.

Finding concurrency bugs by testing is a hard problem.  A non "thread-safe" program might work 100% of the time on one platform (i.e., architecture/OS/JVM combination), it might always fail on some other platform, and its performance in some third platform might depend on what other processes are running, on the time of day or, on other variables that you can only guess at.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically, I know it is not thread-safe, but its kind of hard to proof it by doing tests... Yesterday evening I started reading "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz and others, they basically say the same at the start of the book. Its a shame though, I like proving knowledge :-)

Comment: @ocket-san, maybe you will become a computer scientist...  You can assume that no two memory operations ever happen at exactly the same time when you reason about multi-threaded code:  Every possible execution of your multi-threaded program therefore is equivalent to a single thread performing all of the memory operations in some order (called a _serialization_).  What you're looking for is a technique to prove whether all possible serializations of some program lead to correct outcomes.   But, the number of serializations for most real programs is astronomical.  Good Luck!

Comment: :-) Thanks for the insights. I'll just accept the fact that a concurrent programming is mostly "programming by the rules" and its hard to convince people who don't know the rules that what they write is just not correct. I should also study the rules more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

You can reproduce the concurrency issues when you use more executors at the same time, say `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);` instead of 6. Then more threads will try it at the same time and the probability is higher. Because the race condition/overflow can only happen once, you will have to run your main more times to get more visitors.

Further you need to add a `Thread.yield()` at both places where you expect the "interference", to make it more likely to happen. If the execution is very short/fast there will not be a task switch and the execution will be atomic (but not guaranteed).

You might also write the code using ThreadWeaver which does byte code manipulation (adding yields) to make such issues more likely.

With both changes I get 30 and more visitors in the hotel from time to time. I have 2x2 CPUs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! you got me excited to try it out. When I have, i ll and I have gotten funky results as you say, I ll except your anser!